# Finding gender related words in a text file

Tags: python, string, text, nlp

So let say, I have the following statement as `str` = `What recent discussions she has had with the Secretary of State for Work and Pensions on the effect of that Department’s welfare policies on women`

In the statement, you can clearly see that the question addressed to the woman by a word such as 'she'. How can I find female-specific words in a given text (see above text for example) and for how many times they have been used using python.
For example

```
maleWords = '[He, his]'
femaleWords = '[She,her]'

word="What recent discussions she has had with the Secretary of State for Work and Pensions on the effect of that Department’s welfare policies on women"
```

maleCount = sum(1 if word in maleWords else 0 for word in maleWords)
femaleCount = sum(1 if word in femaleWords else 0 for word in femaleWords)

target_gender = 'male' if maleCount >= femaleCount else 'female'
print(f"text's target gender is {target_gender}")

But the result showing target gender is male while by looking at sentence target gender is female.

Comment: You have to somehow define what a female specific word is. The computer doesn't know that. Either you have a list of female specific words or you pull it from some website on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [this page](https://www.usingenglish.com/files/pdf/genderspecific-words.pdf) to get gender specific words  and add them + he/she to the corresponding list.

```
maleWords = [mw0, m1, m2...]
femaleWords = [fm0, f1, f2...]
```

then count the occurences of words of the text in maleWords vs femaleWords and set the text's target gender to whichever count is higher. eg:

```
message = 'What recent discussions she has had with the Secretary of State for Work and Pensions on the effect of that Department’s welfare policies on women'

maleWords = ['he', 'his']
femaleWords = ['she', 'her']

maleCount = sum(1 if word in maleWords else 0 for word in message.lower().split())
femaleCount = sum(1 if word in femaleWords else 0 for word in message.lower().split())

target_gender = 'male' if maleCount >= femaleCount else 'female'
print(f"text's target gender is {target_gender}")
```

output:

```
text's target gender is female
```

you make the text lowercase first, so (He, HE, hE...) are counted as well.

Comment: I tried to run with your code for a given text. See the modified question. But the answer is not correct.

Comment: You have defined maleWords and femaleWords as strings and not lists, so you are essentially checking against every character of the string when you have to check against every string in the list.`maleWords = ['He', 'his']
femaleWords = ['She', 'her']`  @Ravi

Comment: So I have to convert my string text to list? Right

Comment: If my asnwer was helpful, you can accept my asnwer. @Ravi